# Why is this RegExp taking 16 minutes to process on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I've written a function to remove email addresses from my data using gsub. The code is below. The problem is that it takes a total of 27 minutes to execute the function on a set of 10,000 records. (16 minutes for the first pattern, 11 minutes for the second). Elsewhere in the code I process about 20 other RegExp's using a similar flow (iterating through data.each) and they all finish in less than a second. (BTW, I recognize that my RegExp's aren't perfect and may catch some strings that aren't email addresses.)

Is there something about these two RegExp's that is causing the processing time to be so high? I've tried it on seven different data sources all with the same result, so the problem isn't peculiar to my data set.

```
def remove_email_addresses!(data)
  email_patterns = [
    /[[:graph:]]+@[[:graph:]]+/i,
    /[[:graph:]]+ +at +[^ ][ [[:graph:]]]{0,40} +dot +com/i
  ]
    data.each do |row|
      email_patterns.each do |pattern|
        row[:title].gsub!(pattern,"") unless row[:title].blank?
        row[:description].gsub!(pattern,"") unless row[:description].blank?
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: I can only imagine both of these regexes cause much backtracking, especially when used on long strings. You might want to try formulating your regexes stricter so adjacent quantified character groups don't overlap, e.g. change `[[:graph:]]` in the first regex to some character set that does not include the `@` sign.

Comment: A (simple, quick & dirty) example for such a reduced character set could be `[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.\+]` for the username part and `[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]` for the domain part. You could get an additional performance boost by adding `\b` anchors at the beginning and the end of the regexes.

Comment: I benchmarked these patterns - they're pretty fast. I bet something another makes your code slow.

Comment: @Julian: I was about to write an answer like that, but once I had a similar problem, and the fastest way to solve it was to make basic string search (without regex) to find the positions of `@` or `at` in the string and after to apply a regex in the interval around each positions.

Comment: Can you try on smaller set? 1000 records, for example?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: That's what I'd consider quick-and-dirty, but yes, kind of effective. Those regexes are pretty much easy to optimize, so I'd rather do that than hacking around with searching substrings.

Comment: @Julian: I'm not speaking lightly. When I say I have found that this way is faster, It is because I have tried like you naive pattern optimizations. But the problem remains the same: you can't efficiently find a match for a pattern that begins with a variable length and unanchored subpattern (you can try the character class you want or add a word boundary, the problem stay the same). If you want to speak about dirty ways to solve this problem yours is the best choice: each positions tested * backtracking = ∞

Comment: @Julian: I understand that a one line pattern seems cleaner or faster. But for this particular case, it doesn't work, take a look here: http://regex101.com/r/cG0dL5/1 for only two lines of text the pattern need 660 steps to obtain a single match. If you add a word boundary you obtain 308 steps, but it is far from sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your faster code isn't just doing `var =~ /blah/` matching, rather than replacement: that is several orders of magnitude faster.

In addition to reducing backtracking and replacing + and * with ranges for safety, as follows...

```
email_patterns = [
  /\b[-_.\w]{1,128}@[-_.\w]{1,128}/i,
  /\b[-_.\w]{1,128} {1,10}at {1,10}[^ ][-_.\w ]{0,40} {1,10}dot {1,10}com/i
]
```

... you could also try "unrolling your loop", though this is unlikely to cause any issues unless there is some kind of interaction between the iterators (which there shouldn't be, but...). That is:

```
data.each do |row|
    row[:title].gsub!(patterns[0],"") unless row[:title].blank?
    row[:description].gsub!(patterns[0],"") unless row[:description].blank?
    row[:title].gsub!(patterns[1],"") unless row[:title].blank?
    row[:description].gsub!(patterns[1],"") unless row[:description].blank?
end
```

Finally, if this causes little to no speedup, consider profiling with something like ruby-prof to find out whether the regexes themselves are the issue, or whether there's a problem in the `do` iterator or the `unless` clauses instead.

Could it be that the data is large enough that it causes issues with paging once read in? If so, might it be faster to read the data in and parse it in chunks of N entries, rather than process the whole lot at once?